# Determining the domain of a function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the domain of: $$\left(\frac{5x+4}{x^2+9x+8}\right)^{1/3}$$

I got $(-\infty, -8) \cup (-8,-1) \cup (-1, \infty).$

But according to Wolfram Alpha it is $(-8, -1) \cap [-4/5, \infty)$.

Could someone please tell me why I am wrong? The way I got my answer is by looking at the equation and seeing that a cubed root can be a negative number, but the denominator can not actually equal $0$. Thank you!

Comment: find the roots of denominator

Comment: you are right , may be you don't type it correct in wolfram , may be wolfram supposed it is sqrt ((5x+4)/(x^2+9x+8)) instead of ((5x+4)/(x^2+9x+8))^1/3

Answer (score 1):

Both of you are right. As a real function, $\left(\frac{5x+4}{x^2+9x+8}\right)^{1/3}$ it is defined whenever $\left(\frac{5x+4}{x^2+9x+8}\right)$ is defined, that is whenever $x^2+9x+8 \neq 0$. You already found the roots, $x=-1$ and $x=-8$.

However, as a complex valued function, there is another concept of cubic root, namely the principal root, $x^{1/3} = \exp(\frac{1}{3}\ln(x))$. By default, wolfram alpha computes the domain for the principal root, you can change that by clicking on "use the real-valued root instead".

Comment: That is wrong $x^{1/3}\neq{e}^{\frac{\ln(x)}{3}}$ when $x<0$

Answer (score 1):

By default Wolfram Alpha is interpreting `^(1/3)` as the [principal cube root](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrincipalSquareRoot.html) of 3

What you want to calculate is the real cube root, what you can do this way:

[http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28x%29+%3D+%28+%285x%2B4%29%2F%28x^2%2B9x%2B8%29+%29^%281%2F3%29&a=^_Real](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28x%29%20=%20%28%20%285x%2b4%29/%28x%5E2%2b9x%2b8%29%20%29%5E%281/3%29&a=%5E_Real)

Now even wolfram alpha is saying the domain is $\left\lbrace x : x\neq -8, x\neq -1\right\rbrace$